# How to use annotation in an annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, nested

Given:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation(){
    public SomeType[] value();
}
```

in Java 7 is it possible to do something like:

```
@MyAnnotation({
    value1,
    @MyAnnotation({subValue1, subvalue2, ...}) value2,
    ...
    valueN
})
public Object someProperty;
```

?

Comment: Are you planning to create a framework which will use this?

Comment: Is `MyAnnotation` derived from `SomeType`? (right, I didn't thinks so). Then how do you want to create an array of `SomeType` which includes an element that is *not* of `SomeType` type?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi both `valueX` and `subValueY` are of type `SomeType`

Comment: Yes, but `@MyAnnotation({subValue1, subvalue2, ...}) value2` is *not* a value of `SomeType` type.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi that is the question. Is it possible to make it of type `SomeType` ?

Comment: Nope. In Java you cannot extend Annotation (i.e inherit from Annotation) nether derive an Annotation from something else (i.e. have an Annotation extending a base interface). See my answer for a suggested alternative which may work.

Answer (score -1):

You can. This is an example from [Jackson](https://www.github.com/fasterxml) library (leaving out the comments):

```
package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD,
    ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotation
public @interface JsonSubTypes {
    public Type[] value();

    public @interface Type {
        /**
         * Class of the subtype
         */
        public Class<?> value();

        /**
         * Logical type name used as the type identifier for the class
         */
        public String name() default "";
    }
}
```

And here is an example usage:

```
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TestSystemEvent.class, name = "TestEvent"),
})
public interface SystemEvent {
}
```

Comment: This just explains how to use same annotation multiple times. Does not exactly fit my question. Plus the annotations that are used within each other are different. `JsonSubTypes.Type` used in `JsonSubTypes`.

Comment: Annotations are considered as metadata. They are not objects, so they do not share the same ancestor, Object, with other instances like String.

Answer (score -1):

> How to use annotation in an annotation?

*Maybe* like this

```
public @interface MyAnnotation(){
    public SomeType[] value();

    public MyAnnotation[] refine();
}

@MyAnnotation(
  {value1, value2},
  refine={ @MyAnnotation({valueX, valueY}), @MyAnnotation(valueM) }
)
public Object someProperty;
```

Also, in Java 8, you can have [Repeatable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html) annotations - so you may refine or add to your 'primary' (e.g. the first) other refinements brought in by subsequent repetitions of the same annotation.

Comment: This gives compiler error: `Cyclic annotation element type`

Comment: Well, as I said... "maybe". Fall back into the Repeatable. Or create another annotation with similar value